# How can i edit jupyter notebook from terminal without opening web browser?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

How can I edit my jupyter notebook in terminal.
I just don't like to open jupyter notebook in web browser.
I google out but every answer is related to how can we open notebook from terminal directly.

Comment: What kind of edits are you trying to make? `.ipynb` files are `json` data structures, so this is possible, but an example of what you are trying to do would help us understand how feasible this may be.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest looking at [Jupytext's ability to do command line conversions back-and-forth](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#command-line-conversion) from the notebook json structure to a python script (or markdown). If you already have the backbone of a notebook (`.ipynb`) file, you can convert it to `.py` script using `jupytext --to py notebook.ipynb`. That makes a text file that is easy to edit in your favorite terminal based text editor. The json in the `.ipynb` files is not as easy to edit directly.

Then when you are done editing, you can convert the `.py` script form back to a notebook with something like `jupytext --to notebook notebook.py`. Optionally, you can even execute it without opening a browser by adding `--execute`. I have an example conversion-and-execution command in use [here](https://github.com/fomightez/bendit-binder/blob/3bde602d79c41a31210caf14c7b26d9030e9e12d/bendIt_analysis.ipy#L1026).